# How to return a cross product of a binary function in KDB

Tags: kdb

I would like to explore a better way to apply binary function which iterate via each element of the two argument. Let make the question simpler by using below function as an example:

```
func:{x+y}
a:til 10
q)a
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
b:a
q)b:a
q)b
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
```

What I what to get is the cross production such that each element of the argument will cross each other and apply the function. My expected result is

0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18

My current solution is crossing the the list of argument first:

```
(func/) each (a cross b)
```

I wonder is there a better way to doing that? simply using `func'[a;b]` will just get a pairwise result which not what I want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following should be what you are looking for:

```
a +/:\: b
```

The same can apply for other defined functions too, for example:

```
a {x mod y}/:\: b
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Look like this way is more efficient in term of execution time too

Answer (score 1):

You do not need cross for this just each-right or each-left. Because '+' is a vector function you can just iterate over one list and use other list as full vector.

```
 q) a+/:b
```